# WP7 play audio classes

Tags: windows-phone-7, audio-player

I read that Windows Phone 7 provides many classes for playing audio

[MediaElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement%28v=VS.95%29.aspx)

[SoundEffect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.audio.soundeffect.aspx)

[MediaPlayer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd254850.aspx)

[BackgroundAudioPlayer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh220901%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)

What are the differences among them ? What should I choose

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MediaElement` is a control that sits within the visual tree (which means you need to have it on your page somewhere, even if it's hidden, otherwies it won't play). You can stream songs from isolated storage, your XAP file, or on a network. The supported file types can be seen [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189080%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

`SoundEffect` is an `XNA` component and is, generally, used for things like looping background music or a gun shot. This is similar to `MediaElement` in the sense that it doesn't alter the user's `MediaPlayer` settings, but a difference between `MediaElement` and `SoundEffect` is that you can have multiple `SoundEffects` playing at the same time, whereas you can only have one `MediaElement` control on a page. Also, I believe only `WAV` files are supported. Even though it's an XNA component, it [can be used in Silverlight](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/How_to_play_audio_sounds_in_silverlight_using_XNA_library).

`MediaPlayer` is the system-wide player. It's the one that's used when you play a track from the `Music and Video Hub`, and the one you control when you press the phone's volume button and see `Universal Volume Control` (the overlay the comes down with the the play, pause, next, and previous buttons). If the user is currently listening to a track and they run your app, which takes over `MediaPlayer`, the user's track will be stopped and replaced with your one.

`BackgroundAudioPlayer` is designed to let the user leave your app but continue playing your app's music. This is what the main music player does, which is why you can close the `Music and Video hub`, yet still continue playing music.

What you use depends on what your app is and what you need. There's no one-size fits all recommendation. Also, you should read the app guidelines to make sure your app isn't doing something with the audio that will fail marketplace submission.

Comment: thanks, do all these classes rely on Zune Media Queue? Does MediaPlayer play music in the background like BackgroundAudioPlayer?

Comment: Using MediaPlayer on its own won't let you play music in the background, you will still need to use the `BackgroundAudioPlayer`.

Comment: Is it possible to play two mp3s simultaneously?

Comment: @133t AFAICR, you can only have one MP3 playing at a time. It may be possible on WP8